# macOS Granting full-disk access to sandboxed app not working

Tags: macos, appstore-sandbox, full-disk-access

I'm experimenting with full-disk access and can't make it working. Here is list of steps I did:

1. Sandbox is turned ON. In fact the entitlements file looks like:

```
<key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.files.bookmarks.app-scope</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
<true/>
```

2. I created archive of the app and tried to distribute it using boths *Developer ID* or *Development* methods
3. I placed the binary of my app to */Applications* folder
4. I went to *System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Full Disk Access* and added access to my app in */Applications* folder
5. Of course I'm NOT attached to the app with *Xcode*

I'm testing it in Xcode 11 and on Catalina. It's dummy app, opening `NSOpenPanel` to let user select archives to decompress and tries to decompress it in the same directory.

In fact it's not about `NSOpenPanel`, the question is:

*What is necessary to do to make sandboxed app using full-disk access?*

Any hints? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Does your app use a launch script, or is it only a binary exec?

Comment: I'm quite new to macOS development thus my goal is to learn something new and implement a simple compressing/decompressing app using libarchive as library to do the job. The app can open and decompress associated files, drag-n-dropped files, files selected using NSOpenPanel or opened from FinderSync.
Nothing special, just regular application, not using launch script or XPC services

Comment: Ok, apps that use a launch script need to have the particular shebang interpreter granted file system access by the user in *Catalina*.  But that is not the case here.  Please also post any error messages your are rxing.

Comment: libarchive keeps saying it can't read files. It's working as expected when sandbox is turned OFF

Comment: That means you need to use sandbox-extending entitlements.

Comment: Not sure if I follow. I found this documentation regarding entitlements file: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/app_sandbox

Comment: What is the actual question? What is "not working"? The steps you've listed look fine.

Answer (score 3):

Here is solution [found for iTerm2](https://github.com/gnachman/iTerm2/pull/382) (it is worth read how solution was found). It just adds this to application plist:

```xml
<key>NSSystemAdministrationUsageDescription</key>
<string>I want to read all your files</string>
```

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nssystemadministrationusagedescription?language=objc) is a bit fuzzy.

Sadly this solution doesn't work for `launchctld` daemons (this is what I need). I think daemons are an exception since the do not see UI at all.

But for regular applications it should work like a charm (didn't test it yet).